# Javascript code for email validation as user types email not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've got some code that is trying to verify the validity of an email address as a user is typing it in. I have 2 div blocks setup with different p tag messages - "Valid email address" and "Invalid email address". The JS code I have is supposed to change the visibility of div block depending on the result of an email validation function shown in the code. I'm not sure why the code isn't working.

I have also tried to use just a p tag (with no text) before and change its inner text to either "Invalid email address" or "Valid email address" depending on the validation test. That didn't work either. I tried using a single div block in a similar fashion as well and it didn't work.

Here is the HTML and JS code:

```
<p>Email Address</p>
                    <input type="text" name="email address" id="email" oninput="return validate()"><br><br>
                    <script>
                        var email = document.getElementById("email");
                        function validateEmail(email) {
                            var re = "/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;";
                            return re.test(email);
                        }
                        function validate() {
                            if (validateEmail(document.getElementById("email").value)) {
                                document.getElementById("email_result_valid").style.visibility = "visible";
                                document.getElementById("email_result_valid").style.height = "initial";
                                document.getElementById("email_result_invalid").style.visibility = "hidden";
                                document.getElementById("email_result_invalid").style.height = "0";
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById("email_result_invalid").style.visibility = "visible";
                                document.getElementById("email_result_invalid").style.height = "initial";
                                document.getElementById("email_result_valid").style.visibility = "hidden";
                                document.getElementById("email_result_valid").style.height = "0";
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                    <div id="email_result_invalid" class="email_verify">
                        <p style="color:red">Invalid email address.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="email_result_valid" class="email_verify">
                        <p style="color:green">Valid email address.</p>
                    </div>
```

Here is the CSS code I have:

```
.email_verify {
    visibility: hidden;
    height:0;
}
```

When I tested it on my browser, I tried typing random input into the email address input field, and checked the CSS of the two div tags via developer tools, and found no change in the CSS of the div tags (i.e. visibility remained hidden and height remained 0)

Comment: As a heads up, the only true regex to validate email is `^.+@.+$`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: You need to remove double quotes from your regular expression.  ***var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;***

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: just toggle a class, why set all of the properties with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that your `regex` is a `string`, and second that it is not a correct `regex` for email validation. I changed both and it works, as shown below:

```js
var email = document.getElementById("email");

function validateEmail(val) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(val);
}

function validate() {
  if (validateEmail(email.value)) {
    document.getElementById("email_result_valid").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("email_result_valid").style.height = "initial";
    document.getElementById("email_result_invalid").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("email_result_invalid").style.height = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("email_result_invalid").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("email_result_invalid").style.height = "initial";
    document.getElementById("email_result_valid").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("email_result_valid").style.height = "0";
  }
}
```

```css
.email_verify {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Email Address</p>
<input type="text" name="email address" id="email" oninput="return validate()"><br><br>

<div id="email_result_invalid" class="email_verify">
  <p style="color:red">Invalid email address.</p>
</div>
<div id="email_result_valid" class="email_verify">
  <p style="color:green">Valid email address.</p>
</div>
```

Regex from : [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your regex is working? Because when I check it on https://regex101.com/ this is not working for email.

You sould use this one:
`/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`

Here another stackoverflow post: [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method like this

```
function validateEmail(email) {
   var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; // Need to remove double quotes
   return re.test(email);
 }
```

If you are using regular expression you need to follow any of the below

**var re = /ab+c/;**

or

**var re = new RegExp('ab+c');**

Hope this helps